# Java extending classes mess

Tags: java, extend, extends, identifier

I don't know what pot I was smoking when I posted the original, but I came to my senses and came up with this. I am not an experienced coder, but the entire post was made mostly as a question that for the most part has been answered. I now know classes can't have code directly in them, and more so about the core structure.

class Shape {

```
    public static void ShapeAttemptTwo()
    {
        class Circle extends Shape
            {
                public static CircleAttemptTwo()
                {
                int pi = 3.14;
                int r=4;
                }
            }
        class Rectangle extends Shape
        {
                public static Rectangle()
                {
                int l = 14;
                int b = 10;
                int z = l*b;
                }
        }
        class Square extends Shape
        {
            public static Square()
            {
            int a = 11;
            System.out.println(a * a);
            }
        }
```

// Java code 7, invalid method declare, return type required. (public static //CircleAttemptTwo())
// I'm lost on this one, could I have some help?
// and reached end of file while parsing }, confusing to me.

/EDIT THANK YOU VERY MUCH. The constructive crit. really helped, as I ended up with a lot of knowledge and my final code was

```
class Shape {

public static void ShapeAttemptTwo()
{
    class Circle extends Shape
        {
            public static CircleAttemptTwo()
            {
            int pi = 3.14;
            int r=4;
            }
        }
    class Rectangle extends Shape
    {
            public static Rectangle()
            {
            int l = 14;
            int b = 10;
            int z = l*b;
            }
    }
    class Square extends Shape
    {
        public static Square()
        {
        int a = 11;
        System.out.println(a * a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Each file has one public class in Java because

Answer (score 1):

You're doing several things wrong:

1) Your "static main()" belongs inside a class

2) You can only have one "public class" per module.

SUGGESTED CHANGE:

```
public abstract class Shape 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
      Shape rectangle = new Rectangle (14, 10);
      System.println ("rectangle's area=" + rectangle.getArea ());
      ...
    }

}

class Circle extends Shape  {
   ...
}

class Rectangle extends Shape  {

   int l;
   int b;

   public Rectangle (int l, int b) {
     this.l = l;
     this.b = b;
   }

   public int getArea () {
     return l * b;
   }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you joking? You're missing basic knowledges of Java:

1) Method yea doesn't have a return type.

2) There's a code directly inside the class Rectangle, not in method.

3) There's a code directly inside the class Square, not in method.

4) <s>You're using very strange and weird code-style and formatting.</s>
**Update**: Formatting has been fixed.

**2nd Update**:

1) Code has been changed and it's formatted wrong again.

2) There are three static methods without defined return type.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/) are some more informations related on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the errors Tomas pointed out:

5) You forgot the word `class` in the `Square` declaration.

6) You cannot declare a `public class` directly inside a method.  Java does allow you to declare classes, called "local classes" inside methods.  However, I'm not sure if that's what you really want to do; if you do, you can only use `Circle` inside your `main` method, so you're not really creating a hierarchy.  Anyway, when you declare a local class, it can't have `public`, `protected`, or `private` keywords on it, so that explains the first error message you're seeing.

**EDIT:** Based on the second post: Every method has to have a return type; if you don't actually want the method to return anything, the return type should be `void`.  Thus:

```
public static void CircleAttemptTwo() 
{
    //int pi = 3.14;  should be
    double pi = 3.14;
    int r=4;
}
```

However, *constructors* don't need a return type, but they can't be `static`.  So `public Square()` and `public Rectangle()` are OK.  `CircleAttemptTwo` doesn't match the class name, so it isn't a constructor.

"reached end of file" usually means you're missing a `}`, as you did here.

And 3.14 isn't an integer.

Comment: Isn't the 'static' tag a type? Thanks, I realized the double }} issue. This site is amazing, thank you all for the help.

Comment: No, `static` is not a type.  Types describe what kind of data you're working with, e.g. `int` is an integer, `double` is a double-precision float, `String` is--I'll bet you can guess.  `static` is a modifier (like `public`, `private`, `final`) that conveys some information about how a class or method or variable is used, but it isn't a type.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change

```
int pi = 3.14;
```

to

```
double pi = 3.14;
```

Also, static method is in wrong place.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Could you expand on your answer more?